# How to get updated object array in extended class javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, angularjs, es6-class

Hi all I m new to ES6 classes , currently want to inherit initiated object(this._obj) with updated data, but in the class B i m getting length of initiated object not the updated object?

```js
class A {
      constructor() {
        //intiating array of object with length 0
        this._obj = new Object();
        this._obj['abarray'] = [];
      }
      _renderData() {
        let datas = {
          id: 1,
          name: 'abc',
        };
        this._obj['abarray'].push(datas);
        console.log(this._obj);
        //output
        /*{abarray: Array(1)}
        abarray: Array(1)
        0: {id: 1, name: "abc"}
        length: 1
        __proto__: Array(0)
        __proto__: Object 
       */
      }
    }
    const a = new A();
    a._renderData();
    
    class B extends A {
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
      _showObjectData() {
        //here i want to get the updated object with length 1 as shown in output but i getting as intialized
        /*
        {abarray: Array(0)}
            abarray: Array(0)
            length: 0
            __proto__: Array(0)
            __proto__: Object
        */
        console.log(this._obj);
      }
    }
    const b = new B();
    b._showObjectData();
```

Please any one can help how to achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `_renderData` on an instance of `A` doesn't effect other instances of either `A` or `B`, if you want to call `_renderData` for every instance of `B`, make that call in the constructor itself, otherwise call it on individual instances of `B`.

In the following code snippet, I've created another instance of `A` and stored it in variable `a1`, now if you log `a1._obj` it wouldn't be same as `a._obj`.

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this._obj = new Object();
    this._obj["abarray"] = [];
  }
  _renderData() {
    let datas = { id: 1, name: "abc" };
    this._obj["abarray"].push(datas);
  }
}

const a = new A();
a._renderData();
console.log("a", a._obj);

// Another instance of "A"
const a1 = new A();
console.log("a1", a1._obj); // a1._obj is not same as a._obj
```

#### Calling it in the `constructor` of `B`.

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this._obj = new Object();
    this._obj["abarray"] = [];
  }
  _renderData() {
    let datas = { id: 1, name: "abc" };
    this._obj["abarray"].push(datas);
  }
}

const a = new A();
a._renderData();
console.log("a", a._obj);

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._renderData();
  }
  _showObjectData() {
    return this._obj;
  }
}

const b = new B();
console.log("b", b._showObjectData());
```

#### Calling it on an instance of `B`.

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    //intiating array of object with length 0
    this._obj = new Object();
    this._obj["abarray"] = [];
  }
  _renderData() {
    let datas = { id: 1, name: "abc" };
    this._obj["abarray"].push(datas);
  }
}

const a = new A();
a._renderData();
console.log("a", a._obj);

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  _showObjectData() {
    return this._obj;
  }
}

const b = new B();
b._renderData();
console.log("b", b._showObjectData());
```

Comment: @GoudaPatil Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: can i do same in reverse order, i mean i will remove array data in class B and update it again, can it update same for the class A.